# Remove action woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce you can find [this add_action](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/1b45bcde0b80d19b376fe7557c7bb38adef755bc/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L153):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
```

I don't manage to REMOVE this action with below code:

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

I'm trying to understand why, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a issue that the remove_loop_button function is running much before the function 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button' is added.

Try to run on add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded','remove_loop_button' ); instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. See my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this was added since WooCommerce 2.4, at the time I posted it I had not updated my WooCommerce to 2.4 yet.